# Unparseable date Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, time

I try to call this from Jenkins Pipeline and ended up with an error

```
def setAppBuildDate(buildDate) {
outputDateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy z"
dateTxt = ''
try {
    sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")
    dateTxt = sdf.parse(buildDate)
} catch (java.text.ParseException pe) {
    sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy")
    dateTxt = sdf.parse(buildDate)
}
dateTxt = sdf.parse(buildDate)
APP_BUILD_DATE = dateTxt.format(outputDateFormat, TZ_GMT)
}
```

I got the error like

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: ""
at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassSite.call(PojoMetaClassSite.java:47)
```

Can you please help with this

Comment: from error looks like `buildDate` is empty string

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `OffsetDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: How do you call the function ```setAppBuildDate()```?